# HikariCP + Hibernate + MySql: warnings even when defining correct 'driverClassName' property

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, mysql-connector, hikaricp

I'm having this problem with **HikariCP** and **MySql** in my maven project: a **warning shows** up saying:

> Loading class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver has automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.

I want to get rid of this warning.

For that, I need to know why even having the maven **MySql connector in its latest version** and HikariCP configuration set to set the class `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` (which is the non-deprecated one) this warning still shows up.

Here it is the maven dependency in **pom.xml**:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.16</version>
        </dependency>
```

Then, I have this properties file called **hikaricp-hibernate.properties**

```
jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/local_database
driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

#user and password and other data omitted
```

Now, for the HibernateConfiguration I have:

```java
package mypackage;

// ... imports

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement

public class HibernateConfig {
    private static final String HIBERNATE_PROPERTIES = "/hikaricp-hibernate.properties";

    @Bean(name = "hikariDataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig(HIBERNATE_PROPERTIES);
        HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

In the same class, I register as beans the LocalSessionFactoryBean and the TransactionManager, but the code does not matter here.

I also already checked the configuration in debug mode to see if the driverClassName is the one I have put and the answer is yes.

Therefore, the logs are shown even if registered correctly.

Also, **HikariCP docs** tells me to use the [`jdbcUrl` configuration](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#popular-datasource-class-names):

> The MySQL DataSource is known to be broken with respect to network timeout support. Use jdbcUrl configuration instead.

***Why?***

Does `jdbcUrl` configuration triggers automatically the old Class (if yes, how can I override and avoid this?)? And then it seems that it is deprecated and searches for another one? Does it ignore my `driverClassName` config?

Comment: I can't see any indication of anything wrong in your code there - are you certain that it's definitely being loaded by `HikariCP` and by this code, and not via some other code elsewhere? That would be my first port of call.

Comment: Good question: I don't know. Since I have more applications in my container, I'll try to exclude them and see what happens.

Comment: @MichaelBerry , Thanks for the heads up. What was happening was exactly what you said. There was another application that was registering the deprecated driver. If you want to write an answer with that, I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no issue with the code that's here - the key points being:

- You're listing a dependency on the 8.* branch of the mysql connector, which contains the new JDBC driver
- You're listing the new driver under `driverClassName` in your properties file
- You're instantiating the `HikariConfig` correctly, with the properties that you're defining.

If the old driver is being loaded, it therefore isn't in this code - it's either with a separate application, or somewhere else in this application.